# How to convert a high number of PNG images to JPG forcing the background color?

Tags: batch-processing

I have around 200 hundred PNG small images and I would like to convert all of them into JPG with a black background.

I usually do these kind of batch work with FastStone Image Viewer but there are no option for background color.

Can you suggest me a method and a program that I can use to achieve that result?

Comment: Photoshop is the best..

Comment: @Jack: That would be a matter of debate in these parts. Photoshop is popular, but that doesn't necessarily make it the best.

Comment: yes could be but photoshop is best for the given situation...may be there are lots of other option...no personal attachment with ps :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s command line tools, you could do:

```
$ composite -compose Dst_Over -tile pattern:GRAY0 image.png image.jpg
```

Which

1. Uses pre-generated pattern (`GRAY0`) that is solid black
2. Puts the pattern behind (`-compose Dst_Over`) your png-file `image.png`
3. Tiles the pattern (`-tile`) so it will fill the whole canvas
4. Intelligently saves the composite image as JPG (IM recognises the needed conversion from `image.jpg`'s extension)

Now, the aforementioned command can only do one composite image at a time, but you could hook to and loop it with other command line tools—be it Windows' command line, bash or anything else. (Looking at your profile, you might be most interested in [Windows' tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx).)

Comment: I don't have Photoshop and I tried your solution first, thank you it works perfectly. If you want to add that for people working with XP that usually don't have the ForFiles utility, they can download it [here](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/y2kfix/x86/). This is the batch ready to use: forfiles -m*.png -c"CMD /c composite -compose Dst_Over -tile pattern:GRAY0 @FILE @FNAME_WITHOUT_EXT.jpg"

Comment: Just to complete for Windows Vista or later here it is the command ready to use: forfiles /m *.png /c "CMD /c composite -compose Dst_Over -tile pattern:GRAY0 @FILE @FNAME.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

**In Photoshop** - `Action` and `Batch`or `Image Processor` is what you need:

http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/digitalphotography/l/blps_batch.htm

So this is how it would basically go:

1. Make `Action` where you create a new layer at the bottom and fill it with color.
2. Use `File > Automate > Batch` or `File > Scripts > Image Processor` to execute that recorded Action to all of the images.

**Edit:**

My bad!

I got thinking about it and you can also run Actions through `File > Scripts > Image Processor` as well and as you can convert the file.. if I remember correctly: `jpeg`, `psd` and `tiff` So, it would work better in your case.

So instead of `Batch` use `Image Processor`.

But, I'll keep that part about saving image inside Action because that allows you to save it in more formats than `Image Processor`

---

**Saving image in another format in `Batch`**

Unless cs 5 has way to do this better.. Converting the file format can't be done with batch.

You can however do this:

- As part of the Action where you create new layer and fill it with color, also save the file with the format you want and to the folder you want,  then
  close the document `ctrl+w` and then go to batch and select destination as `none` and run the Batch.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're going to use Photoshop, I suggest File->Save for Web & Devices.  I'm usually surprised how many artists overlook this very handy option (I use it so often I have it hot keyed to F2).

This brings up a dialog that allows you to set the output format to JPG with a specific matte color, automatically flattening your image.  Of course, you can also set quality, color depth, and many other options such as dithering.  This command is also batch-able, and this single step will go much faster.

Although not part of your question, this command also allows you to preview the quality and resultant file size before saving.  You can even compare up to four different settings side-by-side before choosing.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

give this [image programme](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/vb-net-imaging/image-converting/) a shot, it will blow you, also you can do batch conversion.