# How to change thousands of PNG images to JPG formate with black background

Tags: images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a high number of PNG images to JPG forcing the background color?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/how-to-convert-a-high-number-of-png-images-to-jpg-forcing-the-background-color)

How to convert more than 1000 of PNG images to JPG formate with black background in photoshop at a time

Comment: Do your PNG files have transparent backgrounds at present? If so, this is prime for actions, as stated by @utopicam, below. If not, you've got a lot of cutting out to do.

Comment: Also a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is a lot faster than photoshop actions. If it's really *thousands* of images, then this might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be to use **[Image Processor Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2011/05/new-image-processor-pro-script-for-cs5.html)** for Photoshop CS5...(I think you can find it for older versions of photoshop aslo...and you can use it from Bridge witch is nice cause you can see the results faster also...)

Watch how it works in the [**demo video**](http://www.russellbrown.com/Transfer/ImageProcessPro_SM.mov) there. (open link in new tab/window)

Additional info [here](http://www.bernskioldmedia.com/2011/10/05/scripts-coolness-the-image-processor-pro-in-photoshop/) .

The great thing about it is that it supports Actions also, so first you would create the actions, then use it to automate your process, so you don't have to open each image to Run you Actions, Image Processor Pro does that for you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use photoshop actions. These are a series of steps recorded in Photoshop to generate a certain photo effect (or in general, anything you do in Photoshop). This recorded steps can be saved and play-back at later time to achieve the same effect on different images.

In your case, you would have to record your action when you are putting a black background in one of the images, and stop it after you save it in JPG. Because it's different files you would have to create a batch processing.

For one image: http://best-photoshop-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/06/guidelines-to-use-our-photo-effect.html

For more than one image: http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/ss/basicaction.htm